# AWS API Gateway, rewriting discoverability URLs in response body

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Got legacy microservices running on EC2 instances accessed externally via API Gateway. Microservices return JSON responses with discoverability url options:

GET /api/accout/0001

```
  {
     id: "0001",
     balance: 1000000,
     currency: "BTC",
     _links: [
         {name: "close", method: "DELETE", url: "http://10.0.0.1:8080/api/account/0001" },
         {name: "deposit", method: "POST", url: "http://10.0.0.1:8080/api/account/0001/deposit" }
     ]
  }
```

API Gateway exposes the API via https and a custom domain name so links like "http://10.0.0.1:8080/api/account/0001" make no sense externally.

How do I configure AWS API Gateway to replace "http://10.0.0.1:8080/api/account/0001" with "https://api.mycompany.com/api/account/0001" before passing responses from microservices to external api clients?

Comment: "Microservices return JSON responses with discoverability url options like" how is the URL returned? so the OPTIONS HTTP is returning the said url? or is it part of GET response BODY?

Comment: @srikanthNutigattu urls are part of a response body returned on whatever method was called, including GET.

Comment: So the URLs are constructed by your application logic?

Comment: @srikanthNutigattu they are constructed by the legacy microservices that are out of my control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Gateway supports Response transformation and method mapping functionality.

You can define the response templates with required transformation:

[API Gateway Response transformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-response.html)

Based on this:

> If needed, add body-mapping templates to transform given integration
>   response payloads into specified method response payloads.

[Specifically Method Models](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html) which use JSON path expressions, which can be used for transformation.